# Codeigniter admin and user role

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter, roles

I'm making a login system with 2 roles one for 'admin' and one for 'user'. I tried to make a else if statement for the login. This for the user login actually what happens now that every user is going to the admin_view right now.

In my database the row is called 'admin' which is a boolean so if the column 'admin' is 1 in the users table. The admin_view should be loaded if the value is 0 the user_view needs to be loaded.

I really don't know what to do now.

How do I need to seperate the roles between the admin and user?

Here is my controller: users.php

```
public function login() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[3]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[3]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm_password', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|matches[password]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $data = array(
            'errors' => validation_errors()
            );

        $this->session->set_flashdata($data);

        redirect('home');
    } else {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $user_id = $this->user_model->login_user($username, $password);

        if($user_id) {
            $user_data = array(
                'user_id'   => $user_id,
                'username'  => $username,
                'logged_in' => true
                'admin' => 1;
                );

            $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('login_success', 'You are now logged in');
            $data['main_view'] = "admin_view";
            $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);

        } 
        // Here I want the user_view to load op if the user haa a 0 value in 
in the column admin.
        else if($user_id) {
            $user_data = array(
                'user_id'   => $user_id,
                'username'  => $username,
                'logged_in' => true,
                'admin'     => 0;
                );

            $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('login_success', 'You are now logged in');
            $data['main_view'] = "user_view";
            $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);

        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed', 'Sorry, you are not logged in');
            redirect('home/index');
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my model: user_model.php

```
public function login_user($username, $password) {
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $result = $this->db->get('users');
    $db_password = $result->row(2)->password;
    $admin = $result->row(7)->admin;

    if(password_verify($password, $db_password)) {
        return $result->row(0)->id;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
}
```

I apperciate the help.

Comment: what `login_user` Outputs ??

Answer (score 0):

First off, there is a typo in your array, the last one should not end with a `;`.

In your `user_model`, instead of returning the ID, return some more information.

eg:

```
return $result->row(0);
```

Then, when you go back to your controller, you can do

```
$data = $this->user_model->login_user($username, $password);

array(
  'user_id'   => $data->id,
  'username'  => $username,
  'logged_in' => true,
  'admin'     => $data->admin
);
```

From there, you could check in the session data whether `admin` is `0` or `1`.

Then you can do :

```
if ($admin == 0) {
  //send to wherever
} else {
  //send some place else
}
```

Comment: It's not working it only reads my user as 0 but in the database I configured the 'admin' column to one for that user but it is catching 0 now.